# Kernel panic - not syncing - What are some hypothesis for the root cause?

Tags: pi-zero-w, kernel

Kernel: Linux 4.19.42+ #1219 Tue May 14 21:16:38 BST 2019 armv6l GNU/Linux
Hardware: Rasppery Pi Zero W

cat /etc/issue
Raspbian GNU/Linux 9

Kernel panics happen after a day of running with no issues.

Stack trace is in the screenshot:

[image: Kernel panic - not syncing]

What are some hypothesis of the root cause? Hypothesis that can be tested for investigating this issue.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Have you tried unplugging and rebooting it again yet?

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: Thanks! Added os and my question.

Answer (score 2):

From the kernel dump cannot be said very much about the cause of the kernel oops. So you have to narrow down the possible reason. If you have stable software running then it is mostly a hardware defect. First you should look at the [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151) and follow it. Then I would try to run the RasPi with an unmodified image [Raspbian Stretch Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/). If this also fails after some days it is very likely that your Raspberry Pi Zero W has a problem. If it runs stable you should look at your installation what additional software do you have installed that may cause the kernel oops.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! btw, I tired swapping to a new pi, same issue. After upgrading the kernel it hasn't cashed for a while now. Going to test this longer.